# How do you apply function constraints in instance methods in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, constraints, instance, typeclass

I'm learning how to use *typeclasses* in Haskell.

Consider the following implementation of a typeclass `T` with a type constrained class function `f`.

```
class T t where
    f :: (Eq u) => t -> u 

data T_Impl = T_Impl_Bool Bool | T_Impl_Int Int | T_Impl_Float Float 
instance T T_Impl where
    f (T_Impl_Bool x) = x
    f (T_Impl_Int x) = x
    f (T_Impl_Float x) = x
```

---

When I load this into GHCI 7.10.2, I get the following error:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘u’ with actual type ‘Float’
>       ‘u’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for f :: Eq u => T_Impl -> u 
>           at generics.hs:6:5
>
> Relevant bindings include
>   f :: T_Impl -> u (bound at generics.hs:6:5)
> In the expression: x
> In an equation for ‘f’: f (T_Impl_Float x) = x
> ```

---

What am I doing/understanding wrong? It seems reasonable to me that one would want to specialize a typeclass in an instance by providing an accompaning data constructor and function implementation. The part

> Couldn't match expected type '`u`' with actual type '`Float`'

is especially confusing. Why does `u` not match `Float` if `u` only has the constraint that it must qualify as an `Eq` type (`Float`s do that afaik)?

Comment: the constraint is not your problem - the problem is that you are saying: *no matter what `Eq` type you want from me as a result - I can provide it*

Comment: Where do I say that?

Comment: in `f :: Eq u => t -> u` - `t` is know from the context - the `u` is there with an implicit `forall`

Comment: @Carsten Can you link me to a reference for your claim. From what I understand a type constraint only limits potential definitions.

Comment: it's not about the constraint - it's about the `u` - it's really just what Chi pointed out in his answer and comments

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The signature

```
f :: (Eq u) => t -> u
```

means that the **caller** can pick `t` and `u` as wanted, with the only burden of ensuring that `u` is of class `Eq` (and `t` of class `T` -- in class methods there's an implicit `T t` constraint).

It does not mean that the implementation can choose any `u`.

So, the caller can use `f` in any of these ways: (with `t` in class `T`)

```
f :: t -> Bool 
f :: t -> Char
f :: t -> Int
...
```

The compiler is complaining that your implementation is not general enough to cover all these cases.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘u’ with actual type ‘Float’
```

means "You gave me a `Float`, but you must provide a value of the general type `u` (where `u` will be chosen by the caller)"

Comment: This. 1,000 times this. In a typical OO language, *the method* can choose to return anything it wants, so long as it matches the requirements. In Haskell *the caller* gets to choose, not the method.

Comment: This also applies to normal functions that aren't typeclass methods; if you claim you can return "some type that implements `Foo`", you really have to be able to return *any type* that implements `Foo`!

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, chi: That's confusing. Any idea on how to provide an instance definition for the concrete data type?

Comment: @FK82 The return type has to be determined at compile-time. There's no (useful) way to return a different type depending on what input you give it at run-time. Perhaps if we knew what you want this function *for*... but that's possibly a new question.

Comment: @FK82 It's impossible to work with that class, it's promising the impossible, so it can't be implemented. You need to rework your approach. Your question looks like a case of the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @chi Translate it to OOP. E.g. in Java `interface T<U extends Comparable> {
        U f();
}
public class T_Impl_Boolean
        implements T<Boolean> {
        private Boolean b;
        public Boolean f() {return b;}}` works just fine. I don't understand why it would be impossible to implement a type constrained class function for a subset of the constraining class...

Comment: @FK82 This isn't even a typeclass problem. You're trying to write a function that sometimes returns `Bool` and sometimes returns `Float`, but depending on what data you feed it at run-time. You can't do that; the exact return type must be known at *compile-time*.

Comment: Your Java example would be similar to `f :: Eq u => u -> Bool`, where the *input* type, not the return type, has an `Eq` instance.

Comment: @chepner No, it is not. For one, the signature of `f` in `T` makes it clear that the **return type** (`U`) is being parameterized and not the "input type" (there actually is none because, but it would translate to an input of a `T` instance). Also `T` does not implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @FK82 OOP translations are necessarily imprecise, but it is roughly like `interface T { <U extends Comparable> U f(); }` This is promising to be able to produce any `U`, caller's choice.

Comment: @chi Yes, you're right. Btw, with the `MultiParamTypeClasses` pragma enabled, something like `class Eq u => T u t where ...` (roughly equivalent to my Java translation) actually passes the compiler. But the problem is just postponed to runtime. I think I begin to understand the problem a little better though: a typeclass constraint on an open type variable cannot be applied unless the data type is either given explicitely or may be safely inferred. That's why my code is not viable in Haskell.

Comment: not exactly (but it's also a problem) - you code does not work because you your function does not have a unique type - you defined a different return type for each constructor (see chis answer) - you could not do this in java either (well you could use object for them all)

Comment: @FK82 What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Knowing that might help us help you more.

Comment: @DavidYoung I'm implementing a non-monotonic logical system in Haskell as part of my thesis in computer science. In typicall OOP fashion—which of course does not necessarily translate too well to Haskell—you would typically abstract common properties into an interface—e.g. `interface Formula { Formula toCNF(); /*...*/}` (`toCNF` converts to clause normal form)—and then implement this interface for the formulas of each logical system. That's basically what I was trying to do.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, `data Blah a where {Bint :: Blah Int ; Boat :: Blah Float}; hi :: Blah a -> a; hi Bint = 1 :: Int; hi Boat = 3.7`. Whether this is *useful* is another question, I suppose.

Comment: @FK82 Your actual *question* (why doesn't this work?) seems to be answered. Perhaps you should try asking "how do I do XYZ?" as a new question. If you include some details about what you're after, perhaps we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid No it's ok. I understand what's happening now.

Answer (score 10):

Chi has already pointed out why your code doesn't compile. But it's not even that typeclasses are the problem; indeed, your example has only one instance, so it might just as well be a normal function rather than a class.

Fundamentally, the problem is that you're trying to do something like

```
foobar :: Show x => Either Int Bool -> x
foobar (Left  x) = x
foobar (Right x) = x
```

This won't work. It tries to make `foobar` return a different type depending on the value you feed it at run-time. But in Haskell, all types must be 100% determined at *compile-time*. So this cannot work.

There are several things you *can* do, however.

First of all, you *can* do this:

```
foo :: Either Int Bool -> String
foo (Left  x) = show x
foo (Right x) = show x
```

In other words, rather than return something showable, *actually show it*. That means the result type is always `String`. It means that which version of `show` gets called will vary at run-time, but that's fine. Code paths can vary at run-time, it's *types* which cannot.

Another thing you *can* do is this:

```
toInt :: Either Int Bool -> Maybe Int
toInt (Left  x) = Just x
toInt (Right x) = Nothing

toBool :: Either Int Bool -> Maybe Bool
toBool (Left  x) = Nothing
toBool (Right x) = Just x
```

Again, that works perfectly fine.

There are other things you *can* do; without knowing why you want this, it's difficult to suggest others.

As a side note, you want to stop thinking about this like it's object oriented programming. It isn't. It requires a new way of thinking. In particular, don't reach for a typeclass unless you really need one. (I realise this particular example may just be a learning exercise to learn about typeclasses of course...)

Comment: I think I understand the problem now: the type declaration of the class function must either specify a certain data type (this is the most simple case); or, if the type may be parameterized — and hence constrained by a type class — the compiler must be able to safely infer it. Anything else will not pass compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this:

```
class Eq u => T t u | t -> u where
    f :: t -> u
```

You need FlexibleContextx+FunctionalDepencencies and MultiParamTypeClasses+FlexibleInstances on call-site. Or to eliminate class and to use data types instead like Gabriel shows [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html)